# What is the inequality that can be used to determine all of the points that are above $20m$?

Tags: calculus, geometry, algebra-precalculus

The function $f(x)=\frac{1}{30}x^2-6x+100$ models the cables that support a suspension bridge where x is the horizontal distance in meters, from the base of the first support and y is the height in meters, of the cable above the bridge deck. Write and solve an inequality that can be used to determine all of the points that are above $20m$. Write your final answer as a statement, complete with what your solution means.

What I did is made this inequality:

$\frac{1}{30}x^2-6x+100>20$

I then solved it:

$x^2-180x+3000>600$

$x^2-180x+2400>0$

$x^2-180x=-2400$

$x^2-180x+8100=-2400+8100$

$x^2-180x+8100=-2400+8100$

$x^2-180x+8100=5700$

$\sqrt{(x-90)^2}=\sqrt{5700}$

$x-90=\pm10\sqrt{57}$

$x=\pm10\sqrt{57}+90$

I used $x=10\sqrt{57}+90$ and $x=-10\sqrt{57}+90$ for my test:

[image]

Therefore, the solutions to the inequality are $x>10\sqrt{57}+90$ and $x<-10\sqrt{57}+90$

But we only need $x>10\sqrt{57}+90$ since we can't have a negative distance.

Is my solution to the problem correct? Thanks for the help.

Comment: Yes, it is correct https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B30%7Dx%5E2-6x%2B100%3E20

Comment: Not very sure why you discard $0\le x< 90-10\sqrt{57}$, those are not negative distances.  BTW, in many contexts, negative distances could also be meaningful, it just is in a direction opposite to what you are considering as positive... arguably here it may not be used as you are saying the first support is at $x=0$.